# How to get rid of a comma between footnotes in \Chapter in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I separated the footnotes in the Chapter with an comma and I would like the comma to stay in the chapter, but not to appear in the table of contents.
What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[symbol,stable,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr} % header and footer
  \usepackage{titlesec} % adjust the layout of chapters

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1cm}{} 

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{*1}{*2}

%% END USER DEFINED PART
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{blublublu \footnotemark $^,$ \hspace{-0.35cm} \footnotemark}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{bla}      

\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{bli}    

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use the optional argument of the `\chapter` command, for example as follows: `\chapter[blublublu]{blublublu \footnotemark $^,$ \hspace{-0.35cm} \footnotemark}`

Comment: Also, wh not simply use `\chapter[blublublu]{blublublu\footnote{bla}\footnote{bli}}` in combination with the `multiple` option of the `footmisc` package that you already load?